# Восстановление raid1

Tags: linux, raid

Давно был собран raid1 из двух дисков, и после отключения и подключения дисков он перестал работать. Ниже состояние системы. Хотелось бы либо как-то восстановить raid1 или разобрать но что бы сохранились все данные. Боюсь сам что-то делать т.к. не уверент что мои действия не похерят все данные.

sudo mdadm -D /dev/md127

```
/dev/md127:
       Version : 1.2
 Creation Time : Wed Feb 13 09:20:52 2019
    Raid Level : raid1
 Used Dev Size : 18446744073709551615
  Raid Devices : 2
 Total Devices : 2
   Persistence : Superblock is persistent

   Update Time : Sun May  3 09:32:12 2020
         State : active, FAILED, Not Started 
Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
Failed Devices : 0
 Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : unknown

          Name : ivan:0  (local to host ivan)
          UUID : 38a209a7:8550c401:97fccdb1:9ecc0708
        Events : 11529

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   -       0        0        0      removed
   -       0        0        1      removed

   -       8       18        0      sync   /dev/sdb2
   -       8        2        1      sync   /dev/sda2
```

mdadm.conf

```
ARRAY metadata=imsm UUID=30b1f210:55912187:a28538bc:c5127416
ARRAY /dev/md/Volume0 container=30b1f210:55912187:a28538bc:c5127416 member=0 
UUID=231eb1e5:f919e083:281ab926:b124394b
```

/etc/fstab

```
UUID=7bad3cb6-bb1e-4bda-9540-7f5b6f5b9eba /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       
1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=534F-3BB0  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/0EB3EC806C10D573 /mnt/raidArchive auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x- 
gvfs-name=raidAr$
```

ivan@ivan:~$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/sda2

```
/dev/sda2:
      Magic : a92b4efc
    Version : 1.2
Feature Map : 0x0
 Array UUID : 38a209a7:8550c401:97fccdb1:9ecc0708
       Name : ivan:0  (local to host ivan)
Creation Time : Wed Feb 13 09:20:52 2019
  Raid Level : raid1
Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 7813500928 (3725.77 GiB 4000.51 GB)
   Array Size : 3906750464 (3725.77 GiB 4000.51 GB)
  Data Offset : 264192 sectors
 Super Offset : 8 sectors
 Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=0 sectors
        State : clean
  Device UUID : 7f195575:6958b1c5:4e616d83:31c68e9b

  Update Time : Sun May  3 09:32:12 2020
Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
     Checksum : 32c3bd68 - expected 32c3bd67
       Events : 11529


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

ivan@ivan:~$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/sdb2

```
  /dev/sdb2:
       Magic : a92b4efc
    Version : 1.2
Feature Map : 0x0
 Array UUID : 38a209a7:8550c401:97fccdb1:9ecc0708
       Name : ivan:0  (local to host ivan)
Creation Time : Wed Feb 13 09:20:52 2019
   Raid Level : raid1
 Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 7813500928 (3725.77 GiB 4000.51 GB)
     Array Size : 3906750464 (3725.77 GiB 4000.51 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=0 sectors
        State : clean
  Device UUID : 31c49e10:20b74d16:19a55464:20625bcd

  Update Time : Sun May  3 09:32:12 2020
Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
     Checksum : 315da689 - expected 315da688
       Events : 11529


 Device Role : Active device 0
 Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

и вывод dmesg

```
[    3.196857] md/raid1:md127: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
[    3.199736] md127: invalid bitmap file superblock: bad magic
[    3.199737] md127: failed to create bitmap (-22)
[    3.458125] random: crng init done
[    3.458128] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[    3.664009] raid6: sse2x1   gen() 10530 MB/s
[    3.712003] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  7568 MB/s
[    3.760005] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 12582 MB/s
[    3.808005] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  8385 MB/s
[    3.856005] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 15017 MB/s
[    3.904004] raid6: sse2x4   xor() 10298 MB/s
[    3.904005] raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 gen() 15017 MB/s
[    3.904006] raid6: .... xor() 10298 MB/s, rmw enabled
[    3.904006] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm`
```

ivan@ivan:~$ cat /proc/mdstat

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : inactive sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      7813500928 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: Покажите ещё `mdadm -E /dev/sda2` и для sdb2 аналогично. Плюс выдержку из листинга dmesg, там где говорится про диски и сборку массивов.

Comment: Ответил ниже, т.к сюдя почему-то сообщение не поместилось

Comment: И cat /proc/mdstat

Comment: Добавил, только теперь рейд называется md0, после того как я в HOMEHOST прописал свой хост.

Answer (score 1):

судя по mdstat рэйд в порядке, но не запущен

его можно запустить командой(НО, не понятно как в каком состоянии диски!):

```
mdadm start /dev/md0
```

Чтобы сохранить данные я бы предложил, смонтировать один из дисков в отдельную папку, и сохранить их.

Либо если сохранять некуда, то восстановить рэйд примерно такой последовательностью: смонтировать один диск(предварительно удалив его из массива), а из второго создать создать новый рэйд1, пример:

```
удаляем sda1
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sda1
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sda1

монтируем /mnt/first, проверяем что данные на месте

повторяем с диском sdb1(кроме монтирования), и создаём из него новый массив:
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 missing /dev/sdb1
```

получится, новый рэйд1 md1 в деградированном состоянии

создаём ФС, монтируем в другую папку, и копируем из него всё из первой

```
rsync -aP /mnt/first/* /mnt/md1
```

после того как всё будет скопировано, отключаем первую точку монтирования, и добавляем диск в новый массив

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --add /dev/sda1
```

Следим за ходом синхронизации:

```
watch -n 0.2 'cat /proc/mdstat'
```

Внимательно читайте вывод mdadm. По возможности сделайте резервную копию важных данных.